# Copy and rename

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch script that will copy an existing file repeatedly, gradually increasing the number in the file name of the copied file.

I have naively written this

```
for /l %%N in (1 5 500) do copy /y C:\batch\batch.pre C:\temp\g=0.00%%N
```

and have got no further.  Would any of you intelligent chaps and chapesses put me on the right road?

Comment: Check the usage reference by typing `for /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first file is named `batch(1).pre`, the second `batch(2).pre`, and so on, up to 500 files.

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1,1,500) do (
  copy C:\batch\batch.pre batch^(%%x^).pre
)
```